# Are "about:config" changes in firefox readable from websites

Tags: firefox, header, http-headers

Are preferences in the "about:config" section readable from websites?

If so - is there a way to hide the changes that we made?

For example i added a value for general.useragent.override in the about:config and a website seems to recognize this manual change of the value and blocks this traffic.

Usecase:

- I run a surfbar called ebesucher (ebesucher.de)
- Windows get better revenues then linux
- I want to run it in an docker environment

So my idea was to change the useragent within the "about:config" section.

After changing it to "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0" the surfbar stops working.

So - somehow this service (ebesucher.de) recognizes that i changed the useragent manually. If i run it on an original Win10/FF112 it works fine.

How can they achieve to know that i changed the useragent by manual?

May it be the addon which checks for manual changes: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ebesucher-addon1/